# How to check if two segments of an A/B test have significant difference in the treatment effect

Tags: experiment-design, treatment-effect, ab-test, heterogeneity

I am planning to launch an A/B test and there's a concern about a possible primacy/novelty effect. I've decided to segment users into two segments (New Users, Returning Users) and estimate if the effect of the treatment significantly different between the segments. The logic is following: if I detect the difference between these two segments, this should alert me to the fact that returning users react differently to the treatment that the new users, hence, possible primacy/novelty effect.

So far I've read about Conditional Average Treatment Effect and Heterogeneous Treatment Effect but it's just words for me and I can't figure out how to apply the respective methodology to my problem.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You might just use a time covariate and test for sig https://arxiv.org/pdf/2102.12893.pdf

Comment: This whitepaper is actually the only source I have found that talks about detecting presence of primacy/novelty effects (well, there's another one from google employees that this one mentions). But I have a few problems with applying the methodology: 1. in my setting, the metric of interest is a conversion rate and the paper only mentions the case where the user repeats their action. 2. there's no detailed example of applying the described methodology anyways so I'm having a problem with that too. If you could help me with the real example - that would be an immense help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would fit a linear regression model for the expected conversion rate in the four groups of users (treated new, treated returning, control new, and control returning) like this:

$$E[Y \vert Returning, Treated] = \alpha +\gamma \cdot Returning + \beta \cdot Treated +\delta \cdot Returning \times Treated$$

**with heteroskedasticity-robust standard errors**.

This setup assumes that each observation is a distinct user. Binary $Y$ indicates that they converted during the test period. $Returning$ means that this user has some experience with the site/app from before the test starts.

The effect of treatment for new users is $\beta$. For returning users, it is $\beta + \delta$. The null hypothesis that $\delta = 0$ is a test of primacy/novelty effects. Primacy usually means that $\delta < 0$. Novelty means that $\delta > 0$. You could also use one-sided hypotheses here if you are interested in distinguishing between them.

People balk at using a het-robust linear probability model (LPM) rather than a logit/probit, but in a fully saturated model with robust SEs, the estimates of the average marginal effects will be identical, but the effects are easier to interpret with the LPM. Interactions can get tricky in nonlinear models.

Kohavi, Tang, and Xu (2020) has some nice practical references on novelty/primacy, though the book itself does not get as technical as what I wrote above.

---

Kohavi, Ron, Diane Tang, and Ya Xu. 2020. ​Trustworthy Online Controlled Experiments: A Practical Guide to A/B Testing. Cambridge University Press. https://experimentguide.com/

Comment: Thanks! I've read the book and that's where I got a reference to this: https://egap.org/resource/10-things-to-know-about-heterogeneous-treatment-effects/
Any resources that I've looked at are way too technical and lack solid examples though. Even though the mentioned resources seemingly provides the guidance, it's too hard for me to find a way to apply it without any examples.

Comment: @dimitriy It seems like we might need to plot our metric against time after first user visit. then, we look for a steady point such that we find no significant difference in terms of the interaction with time? Then, we filter out earlier values. Thoughts?

Comment: I am not sure if that is doable, given the use patterns at @EugeneKrall's site that he described in the comments on the question. I have seen that approach succeed with tools like email clients or news sites, where usage is more frequent, so one can see how the effect changes as exposure to treatment grows.

Comment: My thoughts were, I don't strictly need to apply methodology designed for estimating learning effects pers se. If I already have two segments - new users who received treatment and old users who received treatment. Theoretically I only need to estimate if there's difference in treatment effect between these two groups and I'm thinking maybe Kolmogorov-Smirnov Test or even Chi-Squared Test for Homogeneity?

Comment: I am not sure that says anything about treatment effectiveness. That simply compares new and returning users who are treated. It would be best if you compared *the effect* for new vs. returning users. The second benefit of estimation is that you might have a situation where the primacy/novelty effect is stat stig but not economically important. Having an estimate helps you decide if that matters.

Comment: @dimitriy that would be ideal but I guess it requires a more complicated approach so I would like to start with something simpler, to make a step in the right direction for starters so to speak. The approximate algorithm I have in mind: 1. perform an A/B test and check if there's statsig difference between control and treatment. When the test is finished, check if there's difference between old users in treatment and new users in treatment. If there is - doubt the results. I don't know where I should go from there though, maybe re-running the test with only new users included.

Comment: I suspect you will find a difference between new and returning users: they often do behave quite differently. But I suspect you will also find that in the control group, so I am not sure how that fact casts doubt on the results of the test. If you add the four conversion rates and the sample sizes to the question, I can do the analysis to illustrate this.

Comment: Hi @dimitriy. Some time has passed and I have finally arrived at the same conclusion as you described above. Thanks for giving me directions! The first time I read your answer I didn't know what the hell you were talking about, now it makes perfect sense!

Comment: @dimitriy another thing. I would be immensely thankful if you gave me an idea as to how I estimate sensitivity and do power calculations for these scenarios. So far it looks like simulations is my best best since I'm not sure they even have a formula for that.

Comment: @EugeneKrall It is best to start a separate question, where you give the equation you want to estimate and any information you have about the data.